# How to enable TLSv1.1 for standalone Mule application

Tags: ssl, mule, java-7

Application uses Mule ESB v3.3 and runs on Java 7.

Mule is started programmatically like this:

```
ConfigurationBuilder builder = new SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder(configResources);
MuleContext context = new DefaultMuleContextFactory().createMuleContext(builder);
context.start();
```

The goal is to enable TLSv1.1 (which is disabled by default in Java7).
I've tried different VM options like

```
-Ddeployment.security.TLSv1.1=true
```

and

```
-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1
```

with no effect.

[Mule documentation](https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/HTTPS+Transport+Reference#HTTPSTransportReference-Fine-TuningSSLEndpoints) says it can be enabled in tls-default.conf, but I have no idea where to put this file since I don't use Mule server, just necessary Mule libraries.

Answer (score 0):

`tls-default.conf` is loaded from the root of the classpath which means that if you place it in 'src/main/resources' (assuming you use Maven), it will end-up in the right place in the built application.

Comment: Can I put the tls-default-conf file in the %MULE_HOME%/conf folder